# Struggling with external css files in Django 1.3 development server

Tags: css, django, web-applications

I am trying to let external css files work on the django 1.3 development server. I read the django's 'managing static files' as well as numerous similar SO questions but I still seem to do something wrong.

Why isn't my css style properly showing when I go to `localhost:8000/page`?

**Directory structure**

```
myproject
|-- manage.py
|-- settings.py
|-- urls.py
|-- app
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- models.py
    |-- tests.py
    |-- views.py
    |-- static
        |-- css
            |-- page.css
|-- templates
    |-- app
        |-- page.html
```

**myproject/views.py**

```
import django.http
import django.template.loader
import django.template  

def page_function(request):
    t = django.template.loader.get_template("page.html")
    c = django.template.Context()
    return django.http.HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

**myproject/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
import myproject.app.views

urlpatterns = patterns('',(r'page/$', myproject.app.views.page_function),)
```

**myproject/templates/app/page.css**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}page.css" />
</head>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>

<p>My first paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

**myproject/settings.py**

(partially)

```
MEDIA_ROOT = ''

MEDIA_URL = ''

STATIC_ROOT = ''

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    "/home/myusername/Desktop/myproject/app/static",
)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'myproject.urls'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    '/home/myusername/Desktop/myproject/templates/app', 
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'app'
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/):

> If {{ STATIC_URL }} isn't working in your template, you're probably
>   not using RequestContext when rendering the template.
>
> As a brief refresher, context processors add variables into the
>   contexts of every template. However, context processors require that
>   you use RequestContext when rendering templates. This happens
>   automatically if you're using a generic view, but in views written by
>   hand you'll need to explicitly use RequestContext To see how that
>   works, and to read more details, check out Subclassing Context:
>   RequestContext.
>
> Another option is the get_static_prefix template tag that is part of
>   Django's core.

Instead of

```
{{ STATIC_URL }}page.css
```

You'll want to use:

```
{% load static %}
{% get_static_prefix %}css/page.css
```

Also note that the directory structure is maintained with static files, so because your page.css is in a subdirectory of 'static', you'll need to load it in the template as 'css/page.css'.

Answer (score 0):

Also replacing

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}page.css" />
```

with

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href={% myproject "app/static/css/page.css" %}>
```

should work.